# different class in different page same information in css

Tags: html, css

example i have two htmls, A.html and B.html, they both uses same styles.css

in A.html, i have class="A_container"

in B.html, i have class="B_container"

in the file styles.css

```
.A_container {
background:url('picture1.jpg');
background-position: 40% 0;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.B_container {
background:url('picture2.jpg');
background-position: 50% 0;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

so the background-size and background-repeat is same in both container, so is there a way i can reduce this redundant?

Comment: no need to write one more class and add it both the place. Better you can make this code is in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a common rule set for both of those classes like this:

```
.A_container, .B_container {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.A_container {
  background-image: url('picture1.jpg');
  background-position: 40% 0;
}
.B_container {
  background-image: url('picture2.jpg');
  background-position: 50% 0;
}
```

Also change background to background-image since it will override background-size and background-repeat properties. The other option is to move the common rule set below the class specific rule sets.

You can find the documentation about rule sets in here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#rule-sets

Comment: i tried your method, but it didn't work, it seemed the line of  .A_container, .B_container {} had no effect

Comment: .B-container or .B_container ? You might have a typo there.

Comment: .B_container, sry i made the typo in the question, changed it now, but i still can't get it to work using your method

Comment: Change background: to background-image: because otherwise it will override background-size and background-repeat from the common ruleset.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Also is there a link i can read about this common ruleset?

Answer (score 0):

You can define rules for multiple selectors using syntax

```
selector1, selector2 { 
    property: value; 
}
```

In your specific example:

```
.A_container, .B-container {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.A_container {
    background:url('picture1.jpg');
    background-position: 40% 0;
}

.B-container {
    background:url('picture2.jpg');
    background-position: 50% 0;
}
```

Comment: same answer given by Henri Hietala